# Application fails to apple but works for me

Tags: iphone, mobile, app-store, submission

I loaded an application to app store and they sent me an email telling me that the application crashes, but I run it on debug and release mode and it works, do you know what could be the problem?.
They said that they did the next:

1. launch app
2. app crashes.

They also sent me a log with the results of compiling the app:

```
Incident Identifier: 343E23E8-5DA5-43E5-A962-F7CA82C50D25
CrashReporter Key:   d91f018f5afc31f948a80025c7a09bb112a3caf4
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         BooksPrice [4074]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/25B1C24E-4E96-449C-9A5E-B203C4F8E457    /BooksPrice.app/BooksPrice
Identifier:      BooksPrice
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-12-20 15:46:55.184 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 0x33b5c000 + 496340
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 0x33b5c000 + 496324
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 0x33b5c000 + 496310
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 0x33b5c000 + 580978
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 0x31b97000 + 281120
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 0x33476000 + 26004
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 0x31b97000 + 273906
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 0x31b97000 + 273990
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 0x31b97000 + 274198
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 0x33476000 + 21700
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07c2 0x33a20000 + 657346
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07fc 0x33a20000 + 657404
12  UIKit                           0x3224b77c 0x32062000 + 2004860
13  UIKit                           0x3224cb32 0x32062000 + 2009906
14  UIKit                           0x3209e86a 0x32062000 + 247914
15  UIKit                           0x3209a1f6 0x32062000 + 229878
16  UIKit                           0x32066484 0x32062000 + 17540
17  UIKit                           0x32065ec2 0x32062000 + 16066
18  UIKit                           0x32065900 0x32062000 + 14592
19  GraphicsServices                0x33b0eefc 0x33b0a000 + 20220
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 0x33a20000 + 218872
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc 0x33a20000 + 218812
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 0x33a20000 + 163702
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
24  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
25  UIKit                           0x32099302 0x32062000 + 226050
26  UIKit                           0x32096e8c 0x32062000 + 216716
27  BooksPrice                      0x00002688 0x1000 + 5768
28  BooksPrice                      0x00002658 0x1000 + 5720

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 0x33b5c000 + 186740
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 0x33b5c000 + 882436
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 0x33b5c000 + 881012
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 0x33b5c000 + 879512
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a 0x33b5c000 + 504394
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 0x33b5c000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 0x33b5c000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 0x30428000 + 749860
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3eaf12e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x31bd9989      r6: 0x00132a5c      r7: 0x2fdfe0f8
    r8: 0x3ea4f538    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0012e4e0     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe0f8      lr: 0x33bd52cb      pc: 0x33bd52d4
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x16fff +BooksPrice armv7  <3ad1d403bf358cd48d63b5161cfbad47> /var/mobile/Applications/25B1C24E-4E96-449C-9A5E-B203C4F8E457/BooksPrice.app/BooksPrice
   0xa0000 -    0xa1fff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30006fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x301fc000 - 0x302e4fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x303d1000 - 0x30426fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30428000 - 0x30a10fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30a28000 - 0x30ad5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30c98000 - 0x30d57fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30d58000 - 0x30d60fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x31266000 - 0x3129cfff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x313e7000 - 0x313e9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x314ad000 - 0x314b8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3164f000 - 0x31788fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x319b5000 - 0x319bbfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31a97000 - 0x31b2afff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31b40000 - 0x31b80fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31b81000 - 0x31b96fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31b97000 - 0x31be1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31c9b000 - 0x31ca7fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31cb8000 - 0x31ceafff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31ceb000 - 0x31cf4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31d30000 - 0x31d37fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31f68000 - 0x31f88fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32062000 - 0x323e3fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32481000 - 0x32483fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3256d000 - 0x3261cfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3261e000 - 0x3262bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32ac8000 - 0x32acafff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32ad8000 - 0x32adffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32b0a000 - 0x32b44fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32b45000 - 0x32b7cfff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32bab000 - 0x32badfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32bae000 - 0x32e48fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32f72000 - 0x32f7ffff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32fc8000 - 0x32ffbfff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32ffc000 - 0x32ffffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x331d0000 - 0x3323ffff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33393000 - 0x333defff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x333df000 - 0x333e2fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33476000 - 0x33537fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x335e8000 - 0x335e8fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33619000 - 0x33738fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33748000 - 0x33795fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33797000 - 0x337b0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x337ff000 - 0x33837fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33980000 - 0x33980fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33a20000 - 0x33b06fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33b0a000 - 0x33b16fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33b43000 - 0x33b48fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33b5c000 - 0x33c6dfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33d6b000 - 0x33d94fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33d95000 - 0x33d99fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x340c9000 - 0x340f8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x340f9000 - 0x341a7fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x341c1000 - 0x342e1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x343c3000 - 0x3446cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3451f000 - 0x3460cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3464e000 - 0x34764fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34774000 - 0x347b3fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34867000 - 0x34886fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34887000 - 0x348c9fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried removing the app completely from your device before the final test? Possibly your app only fails on a clean install because some settings and/or files are missing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the app on an actual device? When Apple rejects your app for crashes, they also explain how you can reproduce the crash, step-by-step.

If your app "supports", meaning you have set specific build settings for certain platforms, then you need to actually test it on that device.

Comment: On which device did they say the crash occurred?

Comment: 4.2.1, When I loaded it I compiled it on 4.1 I don't know if that's got something to do

Comment: Yes, if it doesnt support 4.2.1, it will crash on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to symbolicate the crash log, take a look at this post http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/

Try "Clean All" and then Build (don't forget to delete the app from your device and simulator) and see if the crash is happening on your device/simulator. It might be an assertion failure or un-handled exception.

p.s. You may rebuild and resubmit.